# Rendering SVG in a web page

Tags: html, svg

I have a web page in which i need to show `SVG` logos. This is quite easily possible in the latest browsers, but I need to make it compatible with older browsers too. Some how I need to display an alternate image to the user if the browser does not support SVG.
I have come across a method called `HTTP-content negotiation`, but how can I implement it to get the desired result?
I tried the `<object>` tag but it does not seem to work with IE and is very hard to style when tried with Firefox.

Comment: Have you tried one of the many SVG conversion scripts/tools; for example [SVG Web](https://code.google.com/p/svgweb/)? Those are useful to convert a SVG to a Flash based animation or even an VRML model.

Answer (score 0):

I'd implement this client side with the help of [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). Given a markup such as...

```
<!-- Start with bitmaps because 
they will show up in all browsers even 
if javascript is not enabled -->
<img src="logo1.png" class="logo" />
<img src="logo2.png" class="logo" />
<img src="logo3.png" class="logo" />
<img src="logo4.png" class="logo" />
```

You can do...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (Modernizr.svg){
      $('.logo').each(function(){
         var src = $(this).attr("src");
         var svg = src.substr(0, src.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".svg";
         $(this).attr("src", svg)
      })
  }
})
```